# Не могу разобраться с Git в PhpStorm

Tags: git

Использую IDE PhpStorm. Мне нужно развернуть проект (есть *.zip), залить его в приватный репозиторий на GitHub и залить на сервер.

Всё подключил, склонировал пустой репозиторий, залил туда распакованный *.zip, делаю push, потом pull. Но ничего не происходит.

Можете подсказать, как это делается правильно?

Comment: а коммит перед пушем сделали после того как залили архив?

Answer (score 3):

Сначала вам нужно "зафиксировать" изменения в репозитории. Вы клонировали, пустой репозиторий ---> распаковали туда свой архив. Теперь:

> **git add .** - добавим все новые файлы в индекс гит. (зависит от настроек php storma он может автоматически добавлять файлы в индекс, если они появляются в отслеживаемой папки)
>
> **git commit -m " ваше описание коммита"** - *(ctrl+k)* делаем коммит.
>
> **git push origin** - *(ctrl+shift+k)* отправляем изменения на github

Answer (score 0):

Сам недавно разбирался с Git в PyCharm, но у этих программ одна структура.

Создаете проект, в него распаковываете файлы, и потом, когда ваш проект готов, заходите в **VCS -> Imropt into VC -> Share Project on GitHub**.

В появившемся окне можно указать название нового репозитория, а так же сделать его приватным. После создания репозитория, появится окно предлагающее сделать Push. Введите текст коммита и нажмите Commit and Push

Answer (score -3):

> Create project from version control
>   Добавляем свои файлы, а затем:
>   1. Commit
>   2. Pull
>   3. Push

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?